# Declarative pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i need to execute the jenkinsfile different behaviors, like suppose:

- if the build will trigger manually jenkinsfile executes till build
  stage and
- if the build trigger by change scm/timer then need to
  execute all the stages.

I am a new to Jenkins file(groovy script) so could anyone please help me where and how i can apply condition in Jenkins file. please give me an example for the same with the condition

**Jenkinsfile**:

```
pipeline{
agent any

stage('Checkout'){

     checkout(scm)
 }
 stage('build'){
 echo "build is success"
 }
 stage('deploy'){
 echo " deployment successfully completed "
}
stage('email notify'){
emailext attachLog: true, body: 'job $job has been triggered', compressLog: true, subject: 'Email notification', to: 'mail id'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `when` directive: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when .

Paired up with something like this: `currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()[0].toString().contains('UserIdCause')`, a stage will run whether or not (you decide) if this evaluates to true

This should work:

```
 when {
            expression { return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()[0].toString().contains('UserIdCause') }
}
```

You also have the following from the syntax documentation:

```
when {
            triggeredBy "TimerTrigger"
        }
```

Comment: colud you please give me one example please